# Error Message With Methods Overloaded Method

Tags: c#, .net, methods, static

I am new to C# as you can tell and I've followed a youtube video and I cannot seem to see why I am getting this Error Message with my Method. I know anyone with better knowledge than me would or should probably be able to determine the error straight away so I've posted the code I am using on here.

Any advice, tutorials, or tasks would be greatly appreciated and constructive criticism is met with a welcome.

```
namespace AverageScore
{
 class Program
 {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int Score;
        List<int> scores = new List<int>();
        Console.WriteLine("Please Enter Your Scores");


        string input = "";

        while (input != "stop")
        {
            input = Console.ReadLine();
            int result = 0;

            if (int.TryParse(input, out result))
            {
                scores.Add(result);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine(input + " Is Not A Valid Integer");
            }

        }
        Console.WriteLine("Your Score Is: " + CalculateAverage(Score));
        Console.Read();

    }
    static int CalculateAverage(List<int> Score)
    {
        int result = 0;
        foreach (int i in Score)
        {
            result += i;
        }
        return result / Score.Count;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct this line as follows:-

```
Console.WriteLine("Your Score Is: " + CalculateAverage(scores));
Console.Read();
```

Your method `CalculateAverage` is expecting `List<int>` but you are passing an `int` value "Score".

**Edit:**
Apart from this exception, I have noticed that you are not handling "stop" in your else block of code, so when user will say "stop", your program will say - stop Is not a valid Integer, probably you don;t want this, thus add following block of code in your else part:-

```
else
{
    if (input == "stop")
        break;
    Console.WriteLine(input + " Is Not A Valid Integer");
}
```

Also, if you are calculating average the return type of your *CalculateAverage* method should be `decimal` and not `int`.

Comment: Thank you, I got confused with whether to put 'Score' which belonged to CalculateAverage and didn't really remember scores. Thank you Rahul.

Comment: @connormcwood - Hope that helped! Do mark it as answer if so :)